# Guzzle and XDebug timeout

Tags: php, docker, xdebug, guzzle

I am using Xdebug to debug code with guzzle curl calls.

In any other code, Xdebug works fine.

But whenever there are client calls with Guzzle, All I get is a timeout.

I am using:

- PhpStorm 2017.2
- Docker, with image `richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest` (nginx+php fpm)
- Xdebug on Php 7.1

here is the code snippet, where it freezes:

```
    public function fetch(): string
{
    $content = '';
    $completePath = self::FETCH_PATH . $this->id;
    $request = $this->httClient->get($completePath);
    if ($request->getStatusCode() == 200) {
        $content = $request->getBody()->getContents();
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Are you running async calls?

Comment: no, just default creation with `$this->httClient = new Client(); `

Comment: That's odd. Does the xdebug log say anything relevant? [Relevant article regarding xdebug log with phpstorm in case it's not enabled](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544819-How-to-collect-remote-log-for-XDebug)

Comment: is the target code (servicing the http request) in your project's scope eg your API provider ?  If yes, you must set the maximum external connections to >1  (I run up to 16). Goto `Languages&Frameworks:PHP:debug` in preferences.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg just done that, nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you also set the checkbox `can accept external connections` ? Also, i noticed you are using fpm (ships normally to port 9000, which is also the xdebug port). Make certain you are using another port for either xdebug or fpm.

Comment: yes @YvesLeBorg and as I said, it only freezes with Guzzle.

Comment: @Confidence same thing. Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I believe that the problem occured when two different php process tried to open a Xdebug connection at the same time with the same IDE KEY. (like when you run a test with php cli and the test does a request to your apache/nginx/php-fpm). I assigned a different Xdebug IDE key for cli and fpm and it worked for me.